# How to remove background cells from the excel report generated through jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I'm trying to generate an excel report using the jasper studio, the data is getting populated correctly but the empty rows and columns are also coming in the excel report. I want something like this
[image: desired output]

this is what I'm getting presently, the background cells should be removed from entire report

This is what I'm getting
[image: this is what I'm getting]

I have tried a bunch of different properties but the expected thing was not achieved by them. Any help is appreciated

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="1a1e3695-aaf3-47eb-b517-747f98005114">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="detectCellType" value="true"/>
    <property name="onePagePerSheet" value="false"/>
    <property name="whitePageBackground" value="false"/>
    <property name="ignoreGraphics" value="false"/>
    <property name="collapseRowSpan" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreCellBorder" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set [this property](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background) to false: `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background`

as well as this `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines`

Comment: actually I want the white background to span over the entire sheet, not only where the report contents are there.

Comment: The sheet is infinite while your report is not. So it will not span to the infinite. What you actually can do is hide the grid. See updated answer.